# Deploy dacpac with variable substitution with powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dacpac, sql-server-data-tools

We have the function below that deploys a dacpac. I have been looking to see how to pass variables for the dacpac. Is this possible?

```
Function DeployDB {

param( 
    [string]$SqlServerName = $( throw "Missing required parameter SqlServerName"), 
    [string]$SqlServerUserName = $( throw "Missing required parameter SqlServerUserName"), 
    [string]$SqlServerPassword = $( throw "Missing required parameter SqlServerPassword"), 
    [string]$dacpac = $( throw "Missing required parameter dacpac"), 
    [string]$dbname = $( throw "Missing required parameter dbname") 
    )

Write-Host "Deploying the DB with the following settings" 
Write-Host "Server Name: $SqlServerName" 
Write-Host "DACPAC: $dacpac" 
Write-Host "Name: $dbname"

# load in DAC DLL, This requires config file to support .NET 4.0.
# change file location for a 32-bit OS 
#make sure you
add-type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"

# Create a DacServices object, which needs a connection string 
$dacsvcs = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices "server=$SqlServerName;User ID=$SqlServerUserName;Password=$SqlServerPassword;"

# register event. For info on this cmdlet, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849929.aspx 
register-objectevent -in $dacsvcs -eventname Message -source "msg" -action { out-host -in $Event.SourceArgs[1].Message.Message } | Out-Null

# Load dacpac from file & deploy database
$dp = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load($dacpac) 
$dacsvcs.Deploy($dp, $dbname, $true) 

# clean up event 
unregister-event -source "msg" 

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what you mean by pass variables for the dacpac?  By the way, the above path uses a very old version of DACFx.  The newest version (available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53013) installs to the SQL Server\130\DAC\bin folder.

Comment: Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:DeploymentName. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql) We have a single variable that needs to be passed

Comment: You no longer need to install SQLPackage they have released a NuGet package that contains it. Have a look here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating deploy options as follows and pass them as a fourth parameter to `Deploy()` function.

```
$deployOptions = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacDeployOptions
$deployOptions.SqlCommandVariableValues.Add("SqlCmdParamName", "ParamValue");
```

Comment: Try $deployOptions.SqlCommandVariableValues instead of $deployOptions.SqlCmdVariableValues